# does fabricjs support letterspacing now?(fabricjs 2.0.0-beta5)

Tags: fabricjs, letter-spacing

I am trying to add letterspacing feature to my photo/text editing project using fabricjs.

**Tried code**

```
var newText= new fabric.IText('New Text', {
  fontWeight:200,
  fontSize:30,
  letterSpacing:30,//this line
  fill:"rgb(0,0,0)"
});
```

But not working.
I found that this topic was found in 2015-2016 and think that it's solved now.
But I can't find solution how to use letterspacing in fabricjs.
Topic1: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1974#issuecomment-255216649

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var newText= new fabric.IText('New Text', {
  fontWeight:200,
  fontSize:30,
  charSpacing:1000,
  fill:"rgb(0,0,0)"
});
canvas.add(newText);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Use [charSpacing](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#charSpacing) to give additional space between characters.